# Flash fallback for jplayer won't work in chrome because "Invisible [Flash] content is always blocked."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, audio, jplayer

So I have to use the Flash fallback for Jplayer when the user is using Google Chrome because of the way our audio streaming server is set up (HTML5 just doesn't play nicely with our Streaming Audio Icecast server for some reason, live streams are fine but static mp3s are not). All other browsers are fine!

However, it keeps blocking the player even if the site is selected to always play the flash plugin, and now it's printing this error in the console: "Same-origin plugin content from http://kansaspublicradio.org/widgets/audio-popup/jplayer/Jplayer.swf **must have a visible size larger than 6 x 6 pixels, or it will be blocked. Invisible content is always blocked.**"

What's the best/easiest way to make the Flash player not be invisible?

Jplayer uses HTML elements for the controls. It's not like your typical Flash game or animation or anything, the Flash part is just used to play audio (when HTML5 isn't being uses).

Thanks for any help! I'm also aware that Flash is going away in a few years, hopefully we have a more ideal solution figured out by then.

Answer (score 0):

Open `jquery.jplayer.js` or `jquery.jplayer.min.js` and find `setAttribute("width"`. Here you can adjust the width and height of the loaded player. Setting this to something above 6x6 should fix your issue.

Unfortunately the official `jPlayer` project is no longer maintained and pull requests are ignored, so you'll have to do this manually.